# Cannot access loader.content or width after changing swf app path

Tags: actionscript-3, image, security, classloader

Hi I am new bee to action script 3, and got this question:

My swf app works fine loading remote images using loader. But when I moved the project to a new location in my computer, the images cannot be displayed.

After digging into my code for a few hours, I found out by not accessing the loader's properties such as loader.content or loader.width, the image can be displayed.

Is this related to security settings in as3, or other default settings in relation?

Thank you very much.

Lan

Comment: You can compile file with option "Use Network Services" false  or add this SWF or its folder to trusted in flash player global settings.

Answer (score 0):

Post the URL you are trying to load, probably has some dependencies of the swf's path in there.